# How to access a key of this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have converted my JSON output of facebook post to array, and for searching specific keyword in post's I have to access [message] key, so how to access **[message]** of both the [0], [1] keys below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 459037547545408_496947267087769
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Internet/software
                    [name] => Open Pdf Library
                    [id] => 459037547545408
                )

            [message] => No
            [privacy] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                )

            [type] => status
            [status_type] => mobile_status_update
            [created_time] => 2013-12-17T22:55:55+0000
            [updated_time] => 2013-12-17T22:55:55+0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 459037547545408_496947230421106
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Internet/software
                    [name] => Open Pdf Library
                    [id] => 459037547545408
                )

            [message] => Hello star
            [privacy] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                )

            [type] => status
            [status_type] => mobile_status_update
            [created_time] => 2013-12-17T22:55:46+0000
            [updated_time] => 2013-12-17T22:55:46+0000
        )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo $array[0]["message"];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $array[1]["message"];
?>
```

Should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $foo is your full array...

```
$foo[0]['message'];
$foo[1]['message'];
```

Or loop:

```
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
   echo $bar['message'];
}
```

Comment: did, but displaying only Array()